# Samsung's MultiWindow drag and drop with latest SDK for Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, samsung-mobile-sdk, multi-window

I was trying to implement Samsung's MultiWindow support in an Android app, and I haven't been able to find the [drag and drop feature between MultiWindows](https://youtu.be/7N95OYAwMd4?t=2m40s) that was available in Samsung's S Pen SDK 2.3.

[Latest SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy) for Pen is 4.0.7 and for MultiWindow is 1.2.6: in both cases drag and drop support seems to have vanished - and previous SDK versions cannot be found anywhere.

So, is there any way to support drag and drop between MultiWindows or it is not possible now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Samsung has not included the feature in the latest SDKs mostly due to performance issues that they may have noticed. I found a similar thread on the Developers Site:

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/how-to-implement-multiwindow-drag-and-drop-in-the-new-sdk-103/201/253829?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~&searchSubId=0000000016

I would suggest you to use Android's Drag&Drop listeners to implement the same which is pretty similar to how it was done in the older SDK's.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought multiwindow would require a different drap-and-drop API, but it's true that Android's one runs ok!